# How do I increment through an object in an object in the simplest way possible

Tags: javascript

Hi and just what the question suggests, I need help with my code to increment through an object in an object so that I can use it for a "your cart" feature in an ecommerce website for my project. Here is the code:

```js
var products = {
  product1: {
    name: "Balenciaga Black Shoes",
    quantity: 2,
    price: 50,
    size: "L",
    shipping: 20
  },
  product2: {
    name: "Gucci Pink Bag",
    quantity: 1,
    price: 70,
    size: "Big",
    shipping: 20
  }
};

function myFunc() {

  for (const key in products) {
    for (const key2 in key) {

      console.log(`${key2}: ${key[key2]}`);
    }
  }
}

myFunc()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you're iterating over the *key name itself*, which is just a string:

```
for (const key2 in key) {
```

Instead, iterate over the property named by that key:

```
for (const key2 in products[key]) {
```

Similarly, reference that property when outputting:

```
console.log(`${key2}: ${products[key][key2]}`);
```

You likely also want to output the hierarchy of properties so you know which object had which property value:

```
console.log(`${key}:${key2}: ${products[key][key2]}`);
```

For example:

```js
var products = 
{
    product1: {
        name: "Balenciaga Black Shoes",
        quantity: 2,
        price: 50,
        size: "L",
        shipping: 20
    },
    product2: {
        name: "Gucci Pink Bag",
        quantity: 1,
        price: 70,
        size: "Big",
        shipping: 20
    }
};

function myFunc() {

    for (const key in products) {
        for (const key2 in products[key]) {

            console.log(`${key}:${key2}: ${products[key][key2]}`);
        }
    }
}

myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store your products in an array instead of an object ? Anyway, you need here to loop through all the values of your `products` object then need to loop through all the keys of this product :

```js
var products = {
  product1: {
    name: 'Balenciaga Black Shoes',
    quantity: 2,
    price: 50,
    size: 'L',
    shipping: 20,
  },
  product2: {
    name: 'Gucci Pink Bag',
    quantity: 1,
    price: 70,
    size: 'Big',
    shipping: 20,
  },
};

for (const product of Object.values(products)) {
  for (const key in product) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${product[key]}`);
  }
}
```